# Swift Protocol referencing itself and associated type

Tags: swift, generics, design-patterns, protocols, associated-types

I have a classic implementation of Chain of Responsibility pattern with the following code:

```
protocol Request {

    var firstName: String? { get }
    var lastName: String? { get }

    var email: String? { get }
    var password: String? { get }
    var repeatedPassword: String? { get }
} 

protocol Handler {

    var next: Handler? { get }

    func handle(_ request: Request) -> LocalizedError?
}

class BaseHandler: Handler {

    var next: Handler?

    init(with handler: Handler? = nil) {
        self.next = handler
    }

    func handle(_ request: Request) -> LocalizedError? {
        return next?.handle(request)
    }
}
```

So I can create a PermissionHandler, LocationHandler, LoginHandler, a SignupHandler and combine them in chain. So far so good.

Now I want to create a Chain of Responsibility for other purposes, let's say a MediaContentPlayer CoR with different types of MediaContentHandlers and I thought to refactor and reuse the base code using generics.

So I  started from the Handler protocol:

```
protocol Handler {

    associatedtype HandlerRequest
    var next: Handler? { get }

    func handle(_ request: HandlerRequest) -> LocalizedError?
}
```

but I get error "Protocol 'Handler' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements".

Is there a way to reference the protocol inside the protocol itself when using associatedtype? Or another way to make the above code not dependent on a specific type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would look after something like this:

```swift
protocol Handler {
    // ...
    var next: some Handler<HandlerRequest == Self.HandlerRequest>?  { get }
    // ...
}
```

The problem here is that Swift doesn't (yet) have support for opaque return types that are protocols with associated types.

A solution to this limitation is to use a type eraser for the `next` property:

```swift
protocol Handler {
    associatedtype HandlerRequest

    // shift the generic from a protocol with associated type to a generic struct
    var next: AnyHandler<HandlerRequest>? { get }

    func handle(_ request: HandlerRequest) -> LocalizedError?
}

struct AnyHandler<HandlerRequest> {

    private var _handle: (HandlerRequest) -> LocalizedError?
    private var _next: () -> AnyHandler<HandlerRequest>?

    init<H: Handler>(_ handler: H) where H.HandlerRequest == HandlerRequest {
        _next = { handler.next }
        _handle = handler.handle
    }
}

extension AnyHandler: Handler {

    var next: AnyHandler<HandlerRequest>? { return _next() }

    func handle(_ request: HandlerRequest) -> LocalizedError? {
        return _handle(request)
    }
}
```

This way you can benefit both the protocol, and having the `next` property tied to the handler request type that you need.

As an added bonus for using protocols, you can still benefit the default implementation from the base class:

```swift
extension Handler {
    func handle(_ request: HandlerRequest) -> LocalizedError? {
        return next?.handle(request)
    }
}
```

That's how cool protocols are in Swift, they allow you to avoid classes and use value types for as much as possible, by improving the concept of polymorphism.

---

Usage example:

```swift
struct LoginHandler: Handler {
    var next: AnyHandler<AccountRequest>?

    func handle(_ request: AccountRequest) -> LocalizedError? {
        // do the login validation
    }
}

struct SignupHandler: Handler {
    var next: AnyHandler<AccountRequest>?

    func handle(_ request: AccountRequest) -> LocalizedError? {
        // do the signup validation
    }
}

extension Handler {
    // Helper function to easily create a type erased AnyHandler instance    
    func erase() -> AnyHandler<HandlerRequest> {
        return AnyHandler(self)
    }
}

// now let's put the handers to work:
let loginHandler = LoginHandler()
let signupHandler = SignupHandler(next: loginHandler.erase())
let someOtherAccountHandler = SomeOtherAccountHandler(next: signupHandler.erase())
```

Comment: Looks quite powerful.. however it's still not clear to me how could I now create two specialized and different chains from this base code. I would like to have a chain with a LoginHandler, a SignupHandler, etc. that handles AccountRequest types and a different chain with a AudioHandler, VideoHandler, etc. that handles ContentRequests types. Each handler should be able to override the handle func to add specific behavior conditions. Is this possible?

Comment: @ChristianSlanzi I updated the answer and added a usage example at the end. Hope this makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following

```
protocol Handler {

    associatedtype HandlerRequest
    associatedtype NextHandler: Handler

    var next: Self.NextHandler? { get }

    func handle(_ request: HandlerRequest) -> LocalizedError?
}
```

Comment: looks easy! still have a question though. With this solution, should I create two different BaseHandler classes, let's say a LoginModuleBaseHandler for LoginRequest types and a ContentPlayerBaseHandler for ContentRequest types, or can I also leave a common BaseHandler class and then derive my two different chains for the two different base types? Or in other words, if I defined a typealias in the BaseHandler class, how can I override it/add constraints to it when I derive the specific subclasses of BaseHandler?